# Deleting a value from a named session in PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I create my sessions using the following format and it works for me.

```
$sess_array = array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Bill');
$this->session->set_userdata('sampleSessionName', $sess_array);
```

When needed, I can add more to my named session 'sampleSessionName' using

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('sampleSessionName');
$data['gender'] = 'Male';
$this->session->set_userdata('sampleSessionName', $data);
```

My session looks like this after using

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->session->userdata());

// Output
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1623977779
    [sampleSessionName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Bill
            [gender] => Male
        )
)
```

My problem now is I can't delete 'gender' from the session (or any other value/index, don't which one to call it, when necessary). I tried

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('gender'); // 1


$keys = array('gender');
$this->session->unset_userdata($keys); // 2


$session_data = $this->session->userdata('sampleSessionName');
$this->session->unset_userdata($session_data['gender']); // 3


$session_data = $this->session->userdata('sampleSessionName');
$keys = array('gender');
$this->session->unset_userdata('sampleSessionName', $keys); // 4.1 or
$this->session->unset_userdata('sampleSessionName', $session_data['gender']); // 4.2 or
$this->session->unset_userdata('sampleSessionName', 'gender'); // 4.3
// This number 4 unsets the whole session array
```

How do I delete a value (e.g., gender) from my named session array?

CONFIRMED WORKING SOLUTIONS

```
// 1. Set the value of gender as '' in the session
$data = $this->session->userdata('sampleSessionName'); 
$data['gender'] = ''; 
$this->session->set_userdata('sampleSessionName', $data);


// 2. Saved the values you need in a temp array, destroy the session, create new session with same named and valuesin the temp array.
$tempSessionArray = array(); 
foreach ($_SESSION['sampleSessionName'] as $key => $value) { 
  if ($key != "gender") { 
    $tempSessionArray["$key"] = $value; 
  } 
} 

$this->session->unset_userdata('sampleSessionName');
$this->session->set_userdata('sampleSessionName', $tempSessionArray);
```

Comment: If you can **read** the array into `$data`, why not modify exactly that array?

Comment: which CI version are you using?

Comment: @NicoHaase, actually I can update 'gender' on the session array as '' using the same code adding 'gender' in the firstplace.    $data = $this->session->userdata('sampleSessionName'); $data['gender'] = ''; $this->session->set_userdata('sampleSessionName', $data);   However, I would prefer to delete 'gender' entirely as part of the named session.

Comment: @Vickel, I'm currently using the Codeigniter 3 version.

Comment: If `gender` is a part of the array you store under the name `sampleSessionName`, you have to remove it the xact same way you put it there

Comment: @NicoHaase, the fourth solution I tried (4.1,4.2, 4.3 above) actually uses the method I used to add 'gender' to the array except using unset_userdata and not set_userdata. However, it unsets the whole 'sampleSessionName' session.

Comment: Of course, that's why you should **fetch** the array first, **unset** the data you want to remove, and then **set** the data to the session again. Everything else depends on the implementation of `unset_userdata` which you should probably open to read it ;)

Comment: @NicoHaase, not sure if this is what you mean? So I looped through the session, saved the items I want to save in a temporary array, destroy the session, then create another session with the same name with the values saved on the temp array. Although it looks clunky, it works though.

$tempSessionArray = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['sampleSessionName'] as $key => $value) {
 if ($key != "gender") {  
  $tempSessionArray["$key"] = $value;
 }
}

$this->session->unset_userdata('sampleSessionName');
$this->session->set_userdata('sampleSessionName', $tempSessionArray);

Comment: Although destroying the session in the middle of doing something, even though we'll create another session with the same name, might have some negative implications. The number 1 solution above seems to be looking better for me.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "destroying the session"? Also, why not use exactly what you've listed as a working solution No 1?

Comment: Which version exactly? I'm asking, because there have been problems reported with session for versions before 3.1.11

Comment: @Vickel, I use the Codeigniter 3.1.11.

Comment: @NicoHaase, I'll be using the first solution. Although I would have preferred to have the session variables that are no longer needed to be deleted, I guess that's the next best option.

Comment: Then do so, if you want to. But `gender` is not a session variable on it's on, but, part of an array you put in the session.